# How to make Vertx server to serve request in parallel?

Tags: vert.x

How to make Vertx server to serve request in parallel? If lets say there are 50 user who are submitting HTTP request to vertx server then I want all user request should be served in parallel ?

Asking in context of vertx 2 manual

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is the same than vertx 3: http servers handle requests in parallel, unless you block the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

For all 50 user requests to be served in parallel, run your verticle with increased number of instances which will in short scale your application.

**Run 50 instances of Java verticle,**

```
vertx run MyVerticle.java -instances 50
```

**From vert.x manual,**

-instances : The number of instances of the verticle to instantiate in the Vert.x server. Each verticle instance is strictly single threaded so to scale your application across available cores you might want to deploy more than one instance.

Analogy : one user request/one vert.x instance